# Connect to WIFI from IOS safari browser using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ios, wifi, wifimanager, nehotspothelper

I am trying to achieve a functionality where, users are able to connect to WIFI straight from a webpage/website/browser. From researching, I have found that NEHotspotConfiguration works, but this code is not JavaScript and I am unsure of how to achieve this using JavaScript.

To put things in perspective, I am trying to allow users to automatically connect to WIFI, by fetching user specific ssid and password data and upon loading the page, inserting these in to the wifi configuration setting, so they can automatically connect to the wifi upon page load, or, by clicking a 'connect to wifi' button that I can create.

Any help would be very very appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: You cannot do this using JavaScript in safari. You need to implement NEHotspotConfiguration in an app

Comment: That is a shame. I actually managed to open the setting from safari using JavaScript, but not the Wi-Fi setting. I guess this is good enough, but now, I am trying to open the Wi-Fi settings or just the settings from chrome because of Android. Any pointers? Also thank you for the reply I appreciate it